# Como fazer um input aceitar apenas numeros Binarios <input type="text" name="numero"/>

Tags: html, css

como faço para que este campo aceite apenas numeros binarios que nao aceite 12 nem 13 e etc, apenas numeros 1 e 0, como  0000111 ou 1000 ou 11111??

Comment: Cara nao adiantou ele agora so ta aceitando ou 0 ou 1. tipo um numero binario 11001 ELE NAO ACEITA!! POR FAVOR ALGUEM PODE ME AJUDAR?

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function SomenteNumero(e){
 var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;
if((tecla==48 || tecla==49)) return true;
 else{
return false;
 }
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" size="10" value=""' onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event);">
```

- Uma função é um procedimento de JavaScript - um conjunto de instruções que executa uma tarefa ou calcula um valor. Para usar uma função, você deve defini-la em algum lugar no escopo do qual você quiser chamá-la.
- O evento onkeypress ocorre quando o usuário pressiona uma tecla (no teclado) - neste caso, chama a função.
- keyCode (Keyboard Codes): Representa o número da tecla que o usuário pressiona no teclado 48 é o zero e 49 é o um.
- Se (if) a tecla for zero ou um, tudo bem, aceita (return true)
- senão (else) não aceita.

> Observei que o keyCode agora está [obsoleto](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&u=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode&xid=17259,15700023,15700124,15700149,15700186,15700191,15700201,15700214&usg=ALkJrhjhznIpdfGNn-3C9zs4D9O-azbOQA#Browser_compatibility) e será descartado:

testei com `e.key`

```js
function SomenteNumero(e){
 var tecla=(window.event)?e.key:e.which;
if((tecla==48 || tecla==49)) return true;
 else{
return false;
 }
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" size="70" value=""' onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event);">
```

em navegadores modernos.

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo funcionou!! agora se nao for pedir muito poderia me explicar o codigo.. meu principal foco é aprender...

Comment: (window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which    essa é a parte que nao estou entendendo. o que é este WINDOW.EVENT ai pelo que entendii, se for verdadeiro ele vai pro EVENT.KEYCODE se nao for ele vai para o :e.which; ai gostaria de saber o que sao estes e porque la no INPUT passou como parametro a palavra EVENT.  agradeço se puder me explicar como disse, aprendizado é o meu foco e serei muito grato se me ajudar a compreender melhor

Comment: Alguns browsers guardam a tecla em evento.which e outros em evento.keyCode, e o qualcuno apenas está se certificando de pegar o valor, qualquer que seja o browser. Outra alternativa seria `tecla = e.which || e.keyCode`. Se as teclas apertadas forem "0" ou "1" a função retorna `true`, o que significa: "vá em frente!". Se não for "0" ou "1" retorna `false`, o que significa "aborte o evento".